# Realm.io compacting database

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm using Realm for storage on an iOS app.

The user will be storing binary data inside it (NSData*), and optionally be able to delete certain records to recover space.

Apart from using `writeCopyToPath` and replacing the database, is there any other means of forcing a compactation operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apart from using `writeCopyToPath` and replacing the database, is there any other means of forcing a compaction operation?

That's the only way Realm currently supports recovering "pre-allocated but no longer used" disk space.

Support for automatically compacting Realm files on launch is also something that Realm is tracking: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3289